# Is there a way I can run multiple two and from data points at once in R using ggmap mapdist?

Tags: r, distance, ggmap

I currently have a data set with my data in Latitude and Longitude format.
For example data in column to looks like "46.40267091+-117.04417". Data in the second column looks the same.

Using ggmap I can individual run my code for each location I am trying to calculate the distance.

```
mapdist("46.3957 +-117.0622","46.40267091+-117.04417",mode = "driving")

from                   to                         m    km miles seconds minutes  hours mode   
  <chr>                  <chr>                  <int> <dbl> <dbl>   <int>   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  
1 46.3957 +-117.0622 46.40267091+-117.04417  2183  2.18  1.36     217    3.62 0.0603 driving
```

I am having a hard time running my data all at once since I have 736 rows of data I have to process. Is there a quick way to do so instead of going one by one, which is error prone?

Your help is appreciated

Comment: I presume you are using the Google map API ?  If so, then I've not found any way to run code through the Google API other than by one command (line of code) at a time.  Of course , this could be done with a loop, but it would still be one line of code at a time.   The Google map API provides free data up to their defined limits.  After those limits are reached, Google will be charging your credit card at their defined rates.   In all likelihood, Google can monitor and bill the user's API usage easier when Google processes usage by single increments.  If set, code stops at user defined limits .

Comment: Do you know what loop could be used? I talked to someone else they mentioned trying to use dplyr as a way to work around running each line individually myself.

Comment: Hi.  So now I understand what you are trying to do.  This is actually pretty easy.  I'll send you the code in a little while.

Comment: Hi.  What does you data look like?  Do you have a dataframe?  A list?  Or what?  If you could go about adding an partial example of your data source, then this question can get answered with ease.

Comment: Hi. Yes I have a data frame. Lets call it Test. Then I have a To column and From column with the data arranged as LAT+LONG in each column.

Comment: TO                                             FROM<br/>
46.406333 +-117.049925 46.40267091+-117.04417 <br/>
46.395726 +-117.062265 46.40267091+-117.04417 <br/>
46.306254 +-119.27897         46.2342797+-119.2329393 <br/>
46.275479 +-119.301406 46.2342797+-119.2329393 <br/>
46.281562 +-119.293819 46.2342797+-119.2329393 <br/>
46.288286 +-119.284903 46.2342797+-119.2329393 <br/>

Comment: @gray sorry i can't figure out how to put a readable example in here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As promised, here is one way of achieving what you want using R.  I did this in Jupyter Lab, but that will not change anything.  Here's the code:

Get the To/From data:

```
    df_t <- read.csv("C:/python/R_files/Stackoverflow/To.csv")
    df_f <- read.csv("C:/python/R_files/Stackoverflow/From.csv")
    head(df_t, 2)
    head(df_f, 2)
```

Output:  (Looks good)

```
    A data.frame: 2 × 1
    To
    <fct>
    1   "46.40267091 - 117.04417"
    2   "46.40267091 - 117.04417"
    A data.frame: 2 × 1
    From
    <fct>
    1   "46.406333- 117.049925"
    2   "46.395726- 117.062265"
```

Next, I combined the two dataframes into one dataframe.  Your data might already be combined like this already.

```
    df <- data.frame(from = c(df_f), to = c(df_t))
    df
```

Output: (looks good )

```
    A data.frame: 6 × 2
    From                      To
    <fct>                     <fct>
    "46.406333- 117.049925" "46.40267091 - 117.04417"
    "46.395726- 117.062265" "46.40267091 - 117.04417"
    "46.306254- 119.27897"  "46.2342797 - 119.2329393"
    "46.275479- 119.301406" "46.2342797 - 119.2329393"
    "46.281562- 119.293819" "46.2342797 - 119.2329393"
    "46.288286- 119.284903" "46.2342797 - 119.2329393"
```

And finally, create a function and subset the to/from. Get the data:

```
    dist <- apply(df, 1, function(x){
                   mapdist( x["From"], x["To"]     )
                 })
    
    dist   # run the function
```

You will want to plot the points. I never plotted the data to see if the data or the results make any sense or not.

Output - click the link: ([Just right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bo4bT.png)! )

Comment: Thank you ! You’ve been such a great help. I’m going to give it a try.

Comment: I hope the code worked out for you.  Kindly give an "up Arrow click" next to the answer when you get the chance.  Regards,